# Using Parse findObjectInBackground() to set up a View in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

I'm stuck between two ways of developing my application and am not sure which is best. I was hoping that somebody with a bit more experience or more understanding of Parse could help me.

I am building an iOS app with Swift and using Parse for my back-end. I really enjoy Parse and it's going well.

My question: Say I'm loading a new view. The view is driven by a Parse object, meaning I am setting up Labels, tables, buttons, etc. with data from the object. I load the object in the page load. In this scenario, should I be using the findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock() method? Or should I just be retrieving it, and not moving forward until I do?

Should I just be doing things in the background when the results do not drive the immediate next steps in my code? I am hoping this makes sense. I am running into an issue where if I find an object in the background, then I can't set a label on my view with data from that object until it is found and I have to set it inside the block.

Doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose of finding the data in the background?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of find data in background is not to block the thread. As I understood you, you have to wait for parse to finish getting all the informations, because you have to create your interface with these informations.

So what I would recommend is that you let the user wait, until the interface is ready. For example with a wait-screen or something like that. Or you block some elements which take some time to load. For example a large tableview takes quite some time to load from parse. Especially if your internetconnection isn't that good.

So you should use `findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` whenever possible but only allow the user to access the view, after you've loaded all necessary data to create your view.

What you also could do is do an initial access to parse. So that you set everything up at app-start. That way, you don't have to bother the user later and the user has to wait only one time at the start of your application(or If he wants to reload the tableview. for example)